# How to get model's objects one by one in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I need to make a function that will be launched in celery and will take records from the model in turn, check something and write data to another model with onetoone relationship. There are a lot of entries and using model_name.objects.all () is not appropriate (it will take a lot of memory and time) how to do it correctly.

Comment: can you post what you have tried too?

Comment: I do not know what to try, so I asked

Comment: Can you iterate over your model with id?

Comment: There should be something to bring record in batches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iterator over the queryset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator so your records are fetched on by one

```
model_iterator = your_model.objects.all().iterator()
for record in model_iterator:
    do_something(record)
```